# how to load VideoCaptureDevice Form within aForge demo client

Tags: directshow, barcode, aforge, scanning

I am trying to call the VideoCaptureDevice form within the aForge demo but I am unable to do it. I seem not be able to get it up and running.

I need a way to change resolution or could you please suggest some other way of doing it. I also tried the resolution function but this is giving me some trouble too.

Any suggestions, please?

Thanks in advance and here is the code to change resolution. It might be completely wrong. I do not know that. I use private readonly CameraDevices camDevices; to capture the video from the web camera. The video is ran in a picturebox

```
private void btnSettings_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //resolution
    if (videoDevice != null)
    {
        if ((videoCapabilities != null) && (videoCapabilities.Length != 0))
        {
            videoDevice.VideoResolution = videoCapabilities[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit this question to add the code you have so far?

Comment: Hi Lizz,thanks for your reply. I have got some code which might be completely wrong. It is not working of course. Please take a look again in the original question. Thanks